# Can I monkeypatch a function in another webpack bundle at runtime?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a plugin for a third-party web `application`, whose code I can see but can't modify. I'm running it in Chrome. The main webapp and the plugin are both (separate) webpack bundles. At runtime when the page loads, the webapp fetches the plugin bundles from the same server, and initialises them.

My objective is to make my *plugin* patch/wrap a function in the third-party *`application`*, in the module `webapp/utils/target.tsx`, such that calls to that function from within the webapp have my modified behaviour. Something like this:

```js
// somehow import the `target` module (this is the problem, see below...)

oldFunc = target.targetFunc;
target.targetFunc = function targetFunc(args) {
    // do extra stuff here
    return oldFunc(args);
}
```

But I don't know how to import the `target` module or whether this is possible. Specifically:

- I can't just `import target`, because `application/webapp` is not a dependency of my plugin

  - Plugins are meant to access limited entrypoints that get attached to `window` by the webapp, so they have no direct dependency on the webapp
- I don't think I can add `application/webapp` as a dependency because

  1. it's not a published package (perhaps I can add it as a github link?) and
  2. I don't want webpack to include it in the bundle, so I think I'd have to specify it as an external dependency, but I don't know how to do that...
- I can't modify `application` to do any extra things in its webpack (like exposing `target` in a different way)
- I thought perhaps I could import it dynamically at runtime:

```js
import(/*webpackIgnore: true*/ '/application/webapp/utils/target').then({
    ...
})
```

This gives me the error `Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"`.

If it helps, when the page is fully loaded and the app has loaded my plugin, in Chrome developer tools under Sources -> Page, I see a tree structure like this:

```
- localhost:port
- .
- com.mydomain.myplugin
  - <modules for my plugin>
- application
  - webapp
    - .
    - <other modules>
    - utils
        - target.tsx
        - <other files>
    - webpack
```

Meanwhile the original html page source seems to load the webapp via this tag in the header:

```html
    <script defer="defer" src="/static/main.c4e2eaf1d8c47b01fa6c.js"></script>
```

The Chrome devtools say "Source map detected".

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That the code of the web application is packaged with webpack or not doesn't really matter. The important thing is: how is it included in the html, what code is actually executed by the browser? Does it use native ES6 modules? The structure you say appears in the devtools looks very much like coming from a sourcemap

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - this is exactly the kind of thing I need to learn more about I think. I will look at the page source and update the question

Comment: @Bergi how do I tell if it is using native ES6 modules? The contains of the main js file are one vast anonymous function followed by a `sourceMappingURL` comment.

Comment: Then they probably aren't :-) There would be an `export` declaration at the top level if they were using native ES6 modules. You'll need to untangle that anonymous function - probably an IIFE - and see how they bundled their modules and what kind of loader they use. Hopefully it does have some external (global) entrypoint that you can hook into.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it's an IIFE. I can see in one of the other IIFEs that is loaded a line like `window.Utils = { targetFunc: P.RZ, ...` which is how plugins access the real function. But, if I add a `Proxy` on `window.Utils.targetFunc`, it apparently does not affect calls from within the webapp, only direct calls to that name. So I think I'd have to hold of the actual `P.RZ` object somehow...?

Comment: Yes, you should modify the object, instead of overwriting the `Utils.targetFunc` object (but not the `P.RZ` object) with a proxy

Comment: OK. I think I should give up on this. It doesn't seem to me that any of these internal objects are exposed. There is a `window.webpackChunk_application_webapp` array, and *somewhere* in there may be the object I need to modify, but it's just a mass of opaque functions with minified names.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you can `import` the `module object`, edit with the  `Object. library` and `return` the edited module. If you don't understand nothing but knows the core, these references should helpful to solve this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: Well I can't static import it because it's not a dependency. I tried the dynamic import as shown in my question, but I don't know what I should be using as the path.

Comment: if it's just the directory, localhost maybe missing ``./`` before the directory``application/webapp/utils/target``. this also accepts html requests/addresses(if it's the case).

Comment: if the ``import`` not returns a module(args), it is likely to be returned directly in the page as a sync request(and ``.then()`` is unnecessary). You will have to declare variables like a ``const`` before the import to make the changes.

Comment: The `./application` path is clearly wrong because that would be relative to my plugin code. I tried `/application/webapp/utils/target` but got a different error (edited question)

Comment: I quoted to use ``. / `` Because I didn't understand where you wanted to drop the plugin to load, but in general you can just use the http directory for the request with ``import``, something like ``'https://com.mydomain.myplugin/<path>'``.